# How to resolve DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'namaptn' for row 0.?

Tags: php, json, ajax, datatable, datatables

I want to fetch data from SQL Server, then i send to index.php (With json) to display the data in DataTables. But it give me error like this

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'namaptn' for row 0.

Then I inspect my index.php and I found the json returns this response

> {"data" : [ [{"NoSPTA":"096342","TglBerlakuSPTA":"2017-08-07
>   23:59:59.000","Kdptn":"IA045ZN0HG0","namaptn":"MUNIP
>   KHUSAINI","TglGawang":"07/08/2017
>   14:55:33","TglBruto":null,"TglGiling":null,"TglTara":null,"Netto":"0.0","RF":"","Potongan":"0.0"}]]}

This is my code for index.php

```
<?php

    include "db.php";
    $obj->tglan=$obj->get_hari();
    if (isset($_POST['tanggal2'])) {
        $obj->tglan = $_POST['tanggal2'];

    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/DataTables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/DataTables/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <center>

        <h3>Daftar SPTA<br><?php echo $obj->tanggal("D, j M Y",$obj->tglan);?></h3>
    </center>
    <left>
        <h5>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspLast refreshed : <?php echo $obj->tanggal("D, j M Y",$obj->tglan)." ".date("H:i:s");?></h5>
    </left>
    <br/>
    <form action="viewLaporanUtama2.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group" >
                <label for="tanggal">&nbsp&nbsp&nbspTanggal</label>
                <input type="text" name="tanggal1" class="tanggal" id="myText" required/>
                <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Cari" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
            </div>
     </form>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table border = '0' class="table table-striped table-bordered data" id="tabelSpta">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Nama Petani</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>

                    <th>Nama Petani</th>

                </tr>
            </tfoot>

        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var tabel = $('#tabelSpta').DataTable({


                    "ajax": "database.php",
                    // "sAjaxSource": "data.js",
                    "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
                    "columns": [

                        { "data": "namaptn" },

                    ],  
        });

    });

</script>
<!-- <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.tanggal').datepicker({
                    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                    autoclose:true
                });
            });
</script>
</html>
```

And this database.php

```
<?php

    $serverName="192.168.1.250";
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName; Database=tebu", "sa", "sukseskan");

    $query = "SELECT   a.spa AS NoSPTA,
                        a.tglberlaku as TglBerlakuSPTA, 
                        a.Kdptn, 
                        a.namaptn, 
                            (CONVERT(varchar,b.tgl,103)+' '+ convert(           varchar,b.tgl,108)) 
                        AS TglGawang, 
                            (CONVERT(varchar,c.tgl,103)+' '+ convert(varchar,c.tgl,108)) 
                        AS TglBruto, 
                            (CONVERT(varchar,c.tglgil,103)+' '+ convert(varchar,c.tglgil,108)) 
                        AS TglGiling, 
                            (CONVERT(varchar,c.tgltarra,103)+' '+ convert(varchar,c.tgltarra,108)) 
                        AS TglTara, 
                        case when tgltarra is not null then
                        ISNULL(c.bruto, 0)  - ISNULL(c.Tara, 0) + 0.001
                        else  ISNULL(c.bruto, 0) end
                         AS Netto, 
                            isnull(d.RF,'') 
                        as RF, isnull(d.pot,0) 
                        as Potongan
                        FROM         tblSPA a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                              vtblpos4 d ON a.spa = d.NoSPA LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                              tblbruto c ON a.spa = c.nospa LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                              tblgawang b ON a.spa = b.nospa
                        where a.tglberlaku>='2017-08-07 00:00:00' and a.tglberlaku<='2017-08-07 23:59:59'
                        and left(kdptn,5)='IA045'
                        order by a.spa desc";

            // var_dump($query);

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();

            // $hasil = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $jsonResult = '{"data" : [ ';
            $i = 0;
            while ($data=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
               if($i != 0){
                   $jsonResult .=',';
               }
               $jsonResult .=json_encode($data);
               $i++;
            }
            $jsonResult .= ']}';
            // var_dump($jsonResult);
            echo $jsonResult;

?>
```

I don't know what's wrong with my json, i already type the parameter like the database. How i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an array within an array.  This Datatables doc shows an example of what your JSON should look like:
https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Objects

I think you need to remove the inner array and it should display your "namaptn" field.